# Flask : render_template handling dataframe as html

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am using the following code to render the dataframe values as HTML and which gets directed to a HTML and it works fine.

```
@app.route('/index/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',tables=[df.head().to_html(classes='table table-striped') ] ,titles=df.columns.values )
```

i do have another dataframe which needs to be used in the same 'index.html'.I tried adding the same in the above code like the below

```
 @app.route('/index/')
 def index():
     return render_template('index.html',tables=[df.head().to_html(classes='table table-striped'),**dfrme.head().to_html(classes='table1')** ] ,titles=df.columns.values )
```

It brings up the table one above the other. since i want the other dataframe value to be called in a different area of the index.html need your help for accomplishing the same.

code where it gets rendered:

```
<table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-border">
  <tr>
    {% for table in tables %}
      {{ table|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the template code you are using to render this.

Comment: have updated my code as requested thanks @v25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the first thing to note is that the `DataFrame.to_html` function generates the full table, so there's no need to put the outer `<table></table>` tags in your template.

I would approach this by creating a function, which returns a dictionary to be used in the template:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

# Just define this once
classes = 'w3-table w3-striped w3-border'

def gen_dict(df, title):
    return {'title': title,
            'table': df.head().to_html(classes=classes)
            }
```

Then in your route, where you have for example `df` and `dfrme` as your two dataframes, make a nested dictionary, and pass it to the `render_template` function with dict unpacking:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():

    d = {'df1': gen_dict(df, 'First Dataframe'),
         'df2': gen_dict(dfrme, 'Second Dataframe')
         }

    return render_template('index.html', **d)
```

This then lets you display each table separately in your template, along with the title:

```
<h1> {{df1.title}} </h1>
{{df1.table|safe}}

Some where else...

<h1> {{df2.title}} </h1>
{{df2.table|safe}}
```

Adding more dataframes in future, then becomes a case of adding a similar key/value pair to the `d` dictionary, and editing the template code.

Comment: Thanks a lot i worked like charm @v25. want to clarify can i add graph to the dict  like 'graph': Markup(graph1Plot) for rendering in the same html.

Comment: @Prakash Provided that `Markup` function outputs HTML, then yes this could be added as another item in the dictionary, and rendered with `{{df1.graph|safe}}`.